# Magento - Sendfriend Error

Tags: magento

I keep getting this Magento error emailed to myself:

```
URL: http://mysite.com/sendfriend/product/send/id/1/
IP Address: 66.249.65.69
Time: 2010-03-19 22:23:03 GMT
Error:
Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(184): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/index.php(78): Mage::run('', 'store')
#4 {main}
```

The strange thing is that I have disabled the sendfriend module.  I have also disallowed /sendfriend/ in robots.txt.

Anyone know what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to robots.txt:

Disallow: /sendfriend/

This fixed it for me so I guess it was a google robot causing the issue.